# Unable to run AWS Glue Crawler due to IAM Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I am unable to run newly created AWS Glue Crawler. I followed IAM Role guide at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-an-iam-role.html?icmpid=docs_glue_console

1. Created new Crawler Role `AWSGlueServiceRoleDefault` with `AWSGlueServiceRole` and `AmazonS3FullAccess` managed policies
2. Trust Relationship contains:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. User executing crawler signs via SSO and inheriths `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess`
4. I even tried to create new AWS user with all permissions
   [image: AWS Permissions]

After executing Crawler it fails within 8 seconds with following error:

**Crawler cannot be started. Verify the permissions in the policies attached to the IAM role defined in the crawler**

What other IAM permissions are needed?

Comment: Can you share the role, with all the policies? Is your bucket encrypted by kms?

Comment: Regarding 4) - Did you attach these policies to your role or really create a new user? The user won't help you here as the Crawler will use the permissions of the role you give it.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm having the same issue here.

Comment: I got this error, tried again without changing anything, and it worked the second time. Guessing I did not have enough IP addresses available.

Answer (score 5):

If you're crawling tables and schemas via a JDBC connection to an external data store, make sure you have specified network options to the Glue Connection. I got the exactly same error if the options is not specified. I think the error message is somewhat misleading here.

Here's what I have defined to my crawlers:

1. A role, e.g. AWSGlueServiceRoleDefault with AWSGlueServiceRole managed policies attached.
   [image]
2. Specify the network options to your connections.
   [image]
3. A NAT gateway is created and attached to the subnet you have defined in the step 2 so that there is a public IP available for your crawler to connect to the external data store.
   [image]

If you're attempting to connecting RDS, since the crawler and the database are both in the AWS network, a NAT is not needed. Just define the security group rules to allow the connections. Check the document [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html).

If S3 is the target data source, a VPC endpoint for S3 is recommended. Check the document [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoints-s3.html).

Comment: This should be marked as an accepted answer.